# How to create ksoap2 request with attribute and text node?

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I need to generate a request something like this:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter name="name1">value1</parameter>
    <parameter name="name2">value2</parameter>
    ...etc...
</parameters>
```

I currently have:

```
SoapObject parameters = new SoapObject(namespace, "parameters");
SoapObject parameter = new SoapObject(namespace, "paremeter");
parameter.addAttribute("name", "name1");
```

How do I set the value1 on the parameter object?  It seems like I am missing something simple, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently AFAIK ksoap does not have anything for this. I ran into a similar problem where I had to send an xml with child attributes like that and I had to use `HTTPPost` and create the xml in one big blob string.

You could try doing

```
PropertyInfo req = new PropertyInfo();
    req.name="parameters";// may be different in your case  
    req.type=String.class;
    req.setValue("<parameter name="name1">"+value+"</parameter>"+
                 "<appIncData>"+
                "<int_inc_num>"+int+"</int_inc_num>"+
                " <respTime>"+dateTime+"</respTime>"+
    "</parameters>");

    parameters.addProperty(req);
```

but that did not work for me and I just went with HTTPPost

Comment: Thanks tyczj.   I also just decided to go with httpPost.